# Callback in a for loop with async operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

What is the best way to call a callback function after completion of an async call for all elements of array, from within a `for` loop?

Currently I am checking for iterator to match length of array as follows, but I want to know if there is a better way.

```
exports.myFunction = function (arr, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            var comp = arr[i];

            // do other calculations

            // call an async function
            asyncOperation(comp, function(response){
                // further changes in response here

                // if last array element, call callback()
                if (i == arr.length - 1) {
                    // call the callback...
                    callback();
                }
            });
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Can you please suggest the best approach for this kind of situation?

Comment: Try checking out the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module.

Comment: @zackehh: Please, no more.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha what's wrong with that lib? It's a useful shortcut for this type of thing, and it's pretty widely used.

Comment: @zackehh: We have promises natively now. Callback based operations are on the decline, and the `async` module is basically a collection of hacks to overcome inherent callback limitations which are trivially solved with Promises.

Comment: Hm, this may be a better dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429522/q-promise-nodejs-how-to-resolve-in-loop

Comment: @MadaraUchiha disagree. Lots of people dislike the Promise interface, (not to mention several Node.js TSC members). Node.js has extremely limited Promises natively, and even then only if you're on the absolute latest, which most people aren't. Promises are sugar for the exact same thing, yet far harder to understand as a beginner (IMO).