# Expressjs: Open view after foreach with mysql result.

Tags: mysql, express, foreach, pug

I'm trying to loop with a result from a mysql query and execute a new query in that loop. After looping thru the results I want to open a new view with the result of the first and second query.

Now my problem: The looping al works and I can open the new view, but when opening the view I only get the result of the first query and part of the second query, it opens the view before running the second query another time.

My code:

```
 function getActivitiesDate(req,res, rows)
 {
var rows2 = [];
rows.forEach(function getoutput(item) {
    console.log("getActivitiesDate openend");
    connectionpool.getConnection(function(err, connection3) {
        console.log('Trying to connect to activities date');
        if (!err) {
            console.log('Trying to execute query for activities now'),
                connectionpool.query('SELECT * FROM CALENDAR_ACTIVITY WHERE ACTIVITY_ID =' + connection3.escape(item.ACTIVITY_ID),
                    function (err, rows2) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                            res.statusCode = 500;
                            res.send({
                                result: 'error',
                                err: err.code
                            });
                            connection3.release();
                            console.log('It doesnt work error 500');
                        }
                        if (rows2.length == 0) {
                            res.render('index', {title: 'Index - Calendar Activity not found'});
                        }
                        console.log('Show activities + dates');



                      //  connection3.release();
                    });
        } else {
            console.error('CONNECTION error: ', err);
            res.statusCode = 503;
            res.send({
                result: 'error',
                err: err.code
            });
            console.log('It does not work...');
        }
    });

});
console.log('This is the result of rows2Result: ');
console.log(rows2);
res.render('viewUserActivities', {activities:rows, activityDates:rows2 , title: 'Created activities'});
```

}

the "rows" attribute contains 2 rows for the moment (this could be more, or less, that's why I have the "rows.forEach") but I'm not sure how to pass the result of "rows2" to the new view AFTER it's looped thru the foreach loop for every result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've it's not clear, or you need more information don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have sufficient rep to comment so I might be misinterpreting the question, but can you render the view after the forEach callback has finished?

Like so:

```
function getActivitiesDate(req,res, rows)
{
var rows2 = [];
rows.forEach(function getoutput(item) {
console.log("getActivitiesDate openend");
connectionpool.getConnection(function(err, connection3) {
    console.log('Trying to connect to activities date');
    if (!err) {
        console.log('Trying to execute query for activities now'),
            connectionpool.query('SELECT * FROM CALENDAR_ACTIVITY WHERE ACTIVITY_ID =' + connection3.escape(item.ACTIVITY_ID),
                function (err, rows2) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        res.statusCode = 500;
                        res.send({
                            result: 'error',
                            err: err.code
                        });
                        connection3.release();
                        console.log('It doesnt work error 500');
                    }
                    else if (rows2.length == 0) {
                        res.render('index', {title: 'Index - Calendar Activity not found'});
                    } else {
                          console.log('This is the result of rows2Result: ');
                          console.log(rows2);
                        res.render('viewUserActivities', {activities:rows, activityDates:rows2 , title: 'Created activities'});
                    console.log('Show activities + dates');

                    }

                  //  connection3.release();
                });
    } else {
        console.error('CONNECTION error: ', err);
        res.statusCode = 503;
        res.send({
            result: 'error',
            err: err.code
        });
        console.log('It does not work...');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi yes, that works. But then I don't get all the results from the second query, because it only executes the query once and then it opens the new view. But I need to execute the query for every 'item' and render the view after the loop is finished so that I get all the results back. 

If I try your solution, I only get the results back for the first row in my foreach . 

Is that more clear?

Comment: In that case I would highly recommend the use of promises to defer the action until the loop is finished. The [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) library is a popular choice and I think [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429522/q-promise-nodejs-how-to-resolve-in-loop) is somewhat relevant as an example.


Otherwise, you can use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library and check out their looping functions, like whilst or until.

Comment: If you don't want to use any external libraries, perhaps you could also call an external function within the callback of each forEach loop. This external function can wait until it has been called rows2.length times, and on the final call it will do a res.render with all the finished items. I think this method might be less than ideal though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. That already helped a lot, but now i've got one more question, how do I "add" the result of the second query to rows2 instead of overwriting it in the loop? I know I can push it to an array, but then I always get extra brackets "[" at the beginning and end. And thanks for the help, i'm pretty new to this and I couldn't find much help online.

Comment: It sounds like pushing it is the right approach. I'm not too sure what you mean when you say you get extra brackets at the beginning and end. I'm inclined to think that the second query returns an array with a single element, and when you push that into your rows2 array it results in an array of arrays, e.g. [[1],[2],[3],[4]]. If this is the case then you can extract the data from the second query array before pushing it, e.g. rows2.push(result[0])

Comment: Yep I got it to work. It wasn't a problem with the brackets but the problem was that I was trying to read out the properties wrong. Thanks for all the help.