# insert data into array from redis inside a foreach in node js

Tags: node.js, foreach, node-redis

I have a node js redis api where I am reading data from redis based on key and if not present fetching it from another api and then inserting this data into redis. Also I am pushing this data into a variable and at the end of the foreach I want to return this value to the end user.

The issue is that redis is running in async and as a result my data variable is always empty. How do i get around this?

Here is the relevant part of my code

```
   between.forEach(function(entry) {

    asyncTasks.push(function(callback){

        client.exists(id+entry, function(err, reply) {
            if (reply === 1) {
                client.get(id+entry, function(err, reply) {
                    var output = JSON.parse(reply);
                    data_output = data_output.concat(output);
                });
            } else {
                process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
                var slot_url = "https://" + username + ":" + password + "@testapi.foobar.com/1/timeslots?productId=" + id + "&fromDate=" + entry + "&toDate=" + entry;
                request({

                    url: slot_url,
                    json: true,
                    headers: headers
                }, function(error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                        var data = [];
                        try {
                            var temp = {};
                            console.log(body);
                            body.data.forEach(function(tempslots) {
                                temp['date'] = tempslots['date'];
                                temp['timeslots'] = tempslots['timeslots'];
                                data = data.concat(temp);
                            });
                            client.set(id+entry, JSON.stringify(data));
                            data_output = data_output.concat(data);
                        } catch (err) {
                            console.log(err.message);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("Something went wrong!! " + error.message);
                    }
                })
            }
            callback();
        });
    });

});

async.parallel(asyncTasks, function(){
    // All tasks are done now
    result['data'] = data_output;
    result['response'] = 1;
    result['message'] = 'vacancies list fetched successfully!';
    res.json(result);
});
```

});

the output is always like this `{"data":[],"response":1,"message":"Capacity list fetched successfully!"}` even though I have checked that the code is fetching and inserting data properly in redis

Comment: As we know node js async so your foreach work first and then your radis data will be set .so data output is empty

Comment: @HimanshuGoyal I already know that, I even used async.parallel to get away from this issue but it still wont work. If possible plz give a solution

Comment: You can use promise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429522/q-promise-nodejs-how-to-resolve-in-loop

Comment: I think lot about your code and i found you can use recursive function ,i m always use recursive function to prevent this problem

Comment: I write code for you it may be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalLengthOfItem = between.length;
for (var i = 0; i < totalLengthOfItem - 1; i++) {
    var entry = between[i];
    client.exists(id + entry, function (err, reply) {
        if (reply === 1) {
            client.get(id + entry, function (err, reply) {
                var output = JSON.parse(reply);
                data_output = data_output.concat(output);
                if (i == totalLengthOfItem - 1) {
                    response(data_output);
                }
            });
        } else {
            process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
            var slot_url = "https://" + username + ":" + password + "@testapi.foobar.com/1/timeslots?productId=" + id + "&fromDate=" + entry + "&toDate=" + entry;
            request({

                url: slot_url,
                json: true,
                headers: headers
            }, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                    var data = [];
                    try {
                        var temp = {};
                        body.data.forEach(function (tempslots) {
                            temp['date'] = tempslots['date'];
                            temp['timeslots'] = tempslots['timeslots'];
                            data = data.concat(temp);
                        });
                        client.set(id + entry, JSON.stringify(data));
                        data_output = data_output.concat(data);
                        if (i == totalLengthOfItem - 1) {
                            response(data_output);
                        }
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err.message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Something went wrong!! " + error.message);
                }
            })
        }
    });

}

function response(data_output) {
    result['data'] = data_output;
    result['response'] = 1;
    result['message'] = 'Capacity list fetched successfully!';
    res.json(result);
}
})
```

Comment: won't work @HimanshuGoyal I am getting the error, `cant send header after they are sent` meaning that your function response is being called multiple times

Comment: You just track by using console.log  bcz i do't test it but i think response is call once.

Comment: nope getting called multiple times, for every time the loop runs, strange i am looking into it but i think the good way to do this is using async